# Finding a plane with points and lines

Tags: vectors

I am currently learning vectors so I am quite new to the concept, but I came across this question.

Find a plane that contains the point $A(3, 1, −1)$ and touches the cylinder with radius $3$ whose axis is
the line $p : x = 0, y = z$.

I'm unsure about the notation this question takes with the line, $p : x = 0, y = z$ or another example from another question $p :  \frac {x − 1}{−1}= \frac {y + 2}{2}= z$

Usually aren't lines $y=mx+c$? Can some one explain this and how I am to solve this question?

Comment: Draw a picture to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line $p$ contains (the endpoints of) all vectors with 
$$
x = (0, y, y) = (0,1,1) y
$$ 
where $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

You can roughly interpret this as linear function $y = m x + c$ with (vector) $m = (0,1,1)$ and constant (vector) $c = (0,0,0)$.

Or think of it as the line through $(0,0,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$.

[image: The Situation]

The above image shows the sitation. There is an (infinite) cylinder $C$ along the line $p$ and there is the point $A$.

Your task is to find a plane that touches both. I would interpret this that the plane should contain the point $A$ and does touch the cylinder at at least one point, but does not go through it.

One way to solve this task is to state the general equation of a plane that contains $A$, to state the equation of $C$ and then go for intersection points.

Another way is looking at the geometrical situation and guessing a suitable plane and verifying it.

[image: Guessing a plane]

Comment: does this mean the length of the line p is from the origin (0,0,0) to that point?

Comment: No. $p$ is a line in 3D space. It has infinite length. You can model it as the endpoints of all vectors of the above given shape, that start from the origin.

Comment: When it asks for the plane, in what form do we have to give it in?

Comment: The plane that contains the $x$- and $y$- axes, can be described as $z = 0$. One of the solution planes here has a similiar simple description. Maybe you can guess it from the second image I added.

Answer (score 0):

Lines in the $xy$-plane can be (uniquely) written in the $y=mx+c$ form. However, when you add a third dimension, you also need to define how $z$ changes along the line in a way related to its *projection* on the $xy$-plane.
But hang on, the labelling of axes is arbitrary as long as it is consistent. So we can consider the "old" $x$-axis to be the "new" $z$-axis. That means the "old" $yz$-plane is the "new" $xy$-plane!
So, if we say that our new $z$ is always 0, that simply means our line can be described as one in the new $xy$-plane. But we need to translate back to the old labels, so this is actually an equation in the old $yz$-plane.
Now, this cylinder. You have a point its axis goes through, and a direction vector. This axis can be described by $p=(0,1,1)t+(0,0,0)$, or more simply, $p=mt+c$. Does this form look familiar? All we've done, is exchange a gradient for a direction and an intercept for a position. We needed that change because we're now dealing with three axes, so there are now three different axis pairs to consider; in two axes there is just one pair.
This change can be applied back to two dimensions as $p=(1,m)t+(0,c)$, which gives $x=t$ and $y=mt+c$ - or with the obvious substitution, $y=mx+c$.
Once you get this idea of how to see lines in $2, 3, ...$ dimensions this way, solving the question becomes a matter of manipulating equations to get the result fitting the conditions. You may need to clarify what is meant by "touch" but, if what I would read by it, is a plane through $(3,1,-1)$ and intersects the cylinder along a straight line. So it will share one direction vector with the axis. The other can be found as the direction component of a line through $(3,1,-1)$ which is a tangent to the cylinder. There are two possibilities for this: a plane going to either side of the cylinder.